# Creating a data frame from a CSV file with embedded lists

Tags: r

I'm still rather new to R and may have gotten the concept of data frames completely messed up.

But I have a csv file in the following format:

```
ID;Year;Title;Authors;Keywords;
```

Where Authors and Keywords are supposed to be a list of strings. E.g.

> 1;2013;Towards Dynamic Non-obtrusive Health Monitoring Based on SOA and Cloud;Mohammed Serhani,  Abdelghani Benharret, Erlabi Badidi;E-health, Diseases, Monitoring, Prevention, SOA, Cloud, Platform, m-tech;

Is there a way to read this csv file into R so that the data frame columns for Authors and Keywords are built as lists of lists? And does this require me to format the csv file in a specific way?

Reading the csv with the following options

```
articles <- read.csv(file="ls.csv",head=TRUE,sep=";",stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Yields the Authors colum as a list containing character instances. But what I'm trying to achieve is getting a list of characters in each field in the Authors column.

Answer (score 3):

Are you saying that your file contains five variables (ID, year, title, authors, keywords) that are separated by semicolons? Then, by definition, it's not a csv file! Remember that csv stands for *comma*-separated values. Somebody screwed up by naming it as such.

You can read arbitrarily-delimited data using `read.table`:

```
articles <- read.table("ls.csv", header=TRUE, sep=";", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: In many countries the comma is used as a decimal separator and, therefore, the semicolon is used in csv files (yes, they are still called csv files) as column seperator. `read.table` works, but there is also a `read.csv2` for these files.

Comment: @JanvanderLaan - 'in many countries...' As far as i know only the Dutch use this convention and it is one of the reasons why I *hate* using the Dutch Excel version, especially when collaborating with people who have the international version. +1 for mentioning `read.csv2`!

Comment: @nluigi There are more countries using the comma than the period as decimal separator (perhaps not people as china and india use the period) . See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Countries_using_Arabic_numerals_with_decimal_comma . I don't know what the spreadsheets in those countries do. But I agree that the fact that the behaviour of excel is locale dependent, is quite annoying.

Comment: @JanvanderLaan wow didn't realize so many countries use this convention. And we make fun of Americans for using the imperial system :(...

Answer (score 0):

Like Hong Ooi pointed out, your fields are separated by ';', not ','. Function *read.csv* has default value *sep=","* while *read.csv2* has default *sep=";"*. If I understood correctly, your fields *Authors* and *Keywords* are separated by ',' and you wish to separate these as well.

I do not think you could have a list type of items in columns *Authors* and *Keywords* in a data.frame, as the column of a data.frame cannot be a list. If a list is given to a data.frame, it is broken down to its column components. In your case it will not work as there will be a varying number of authors and/or keywords:

```
# Works
data.frame(a=list(first=1:3, second=letters[1:3]), b=list(first=4:6, second=LETTERS[1:3]))
#  a.first a.second b.first b.second
#1       1        a       4        A
#2       2        b       5        B
#3       3        c       6        C

# Does not work
data.frame(a=list(first=1:3, second=letters[1:2]), b=list(first=4:6, second=LETTERS[1:6]))
#Error in data.frame(first = 1:3, second = c("a", "b"), check.names = FALSE,  : 
#  arguments imply differing number of rows: 3, 2
```

But since a list may contain lists, you could try break the data frame down to such. Contents of 'example.txt':

```
ID;Year;Title;Authors;Keywords;
1;2013;Towards Dynamic Non-obtrusive Health Monitoring Based on SOA and Cloud;Mohammed Serhani, Abdelghani Benharret, Erlabi Badidi;E-health, Diseases, Monitoring, Prevention, SOA, Cloud, Platform, m-tech;
2;1234;Title2;Author1, Author2;Key1, Key2, Key3;
3;5678;Title3;Author3, Author4, Author5;Key1, Key2, Key4;
```

Here is an example of how to do it:

```
x <- scan("example.txt", what="", sep="\n", strip.white=TRUE)
y <- strsplit(x, ";")
# Leave out the header
dat <- y[-1]

# Apply a function to every element inside the highest level list
dat <- lapply(dat, 
    FUN=function(x) {
        # Splits in authors and keywords list
        ret <- strsplit(x, ",");
        # Remove leading and trailing whitespace
        ret <- lapply(ret, FUN=function(z) gsub("(^ +)|( +$)", "", z));
        # Assign names to all the fields
        names(ret)<-unlist(y[1]); 
        ret
    }
)
```

Output:

```
> str(dat)
List of 3
 $ :List of 5
  ..$ ID      : chr "1"
  ..$ Year    : chr "2013"
  ..$ Title   : chr "Towards Dynamic Non-obtrusive Health Monitoring Based on SOA and Cloud"
  ..$ Authors : chr [1:3] "Mohammed Serhani" "Abdelghani Benharret" "Erlabi Badidi"
  ..$ Keywords: chr [1:8] "E-health" "Diseases" "Monitoring" "Prevention" ...
 $ :List of 5
  ..$ ID      : chr "2"
  ..$ Year    : chr "1234"
  ..$ Title   : chr "Title2"
  ..$ Authors : chr [1:2] "Author1" "Author2"
  ..$ Keywords: chr [1:3] "Key1" "Key2" "Key3"
 $ :List of 5
  ..$ ID      : chr "3"
  ..$ Year    : chr "5678"
  ..$ Title   : chr "Title3"
  ..$ Authors : chr [1:3] "Author3" "Author4" "Author5"
  ..$ Keywords: chr [1:3] "Key1" "Key2" "Key4"

# Keywords of first item
> dat[[1]]$Keywords
[1] "E-health"   "Diseases"   "Monitoring" "Prevention" "SOA"       
[6] "Cloud"      "Platform"   "m-tech"  

# Title of second item
> dat[[2]][[3]]
[1] "Title2"

# Traveling inside the list of lists, accessing the very last data element
> lastitem <- length(dat)
> lastfield <- length(dat[[lastitem]])
> lastkey <- length(dat[[lastitem]][[lastfield]])
> dat[[lastitem]][[lastfield]][[lastkey]]
[1] "Key4"
```

Notice that lists of lists may be an inefficient way to store data in R, so if you have lots of data you may want to move to a more efficient method, e.g. relational database structure where the access key is your ID, assuming it is unique.